# Split Comma seperated value other than split function

Tags: sql, sql-server

FOR EACH LINE THERE IS AN VALID Patient_id ASSOCIATED WITH IT in Parent table
i try to validate whether correct Patient_id linked with line.

**problem:**
In child table Patient_id is **comma seperated**.
if i am using function to split value, the query is not completing even after
15 hours.

**can anyone suggest some other alternate, without using finction Please if possible**

```
DECLARE @PARENT_TABLE TABLE
(

Line VARCHAR (50),
Patient_id  VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @PARENT_TABLE

SELECT 'ABSRB', 'E001' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABSRB', 'E067' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABSRB', 'E068'



DECLARE @CHILD_TABLE TABLE
(
LINE VARCHAR (50),
SKU VARCHAR (50),
Patient_id VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT @CHILD_TABLE

SELECT 'ABSRB', 'PRS317580',    NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABSRB', 'RANRS7371',    'E001' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABSRB', 'KYBKG54327',   'E067' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABSRB', 'KYB344615',     'V048, V055, E068' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABSRB', 'ZZZZ15245',     'S128, V048, V055'

SELECT * FROM @CHILD_TABLE
```

can anyone suggest some other alternate, without using finction Please if possible

i have not included split function code here.

Code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString](
   @string NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @delimiter CHAR(1),
   @keylist nvarchar(50)) 
  RETURNS TABLE
     AS
     RETURN(
     WITH CTE AS(
     SELECT 1 as n
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 1
     ),CTE2 AS(
         SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c.n) as n
         FROM CTE c
         CROSS JOIN CTE c2
         CROSS JOIN CTE c3
         CROSS JOIN CTE c4
         CROSS JOIN CTE c5
         CROSS JOIN CTE c6
     )

     SELECT TOP(LEN(COALESCE(@string,''))) 
       splitdata = ltrim(rtrim(
         SUBSTRING(@string, n, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string  + @delimiter, n)-n)
       )), 
       keyname= @keylist 
     FROM CTE2 
     WHERE n<= LEN(@string)
     AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @string , n, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
     )



  DECLARE @SplittedTable TABLE
  (   
  splitted    VARCHAR (50),
  keys VARCHAR (50)
  )


  INSERT INTO @SplittedTable(splitted,keys)
     SELECT ss.splitdata, ss.keyname
     FROM @CHILD_TABLE ct 
     CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(ct.Patient_id,',',ct.Patient_id) ss



  SELECT * FROM @CHILD_TABLE ct WHERE ct.Patient_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT st.keys 
  FROM @SplittedTable AS st 
  WHERE st.splitted  NOT IN (SELECT Patient_id FROM @Parent_table m ));



      SELECT DISTINCT ct.*
      FROM @CHILD_TABLE ct 
      CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(ct.Patient_id,',',ct.Patient_id) ss
     WHERE ss.splitdata NOT IN (SELECT Patient_id FROM @Parent_table)
```

**The below code took more than 15 hours to execute. table size: 20GB**

CODE:

```
--selecting by keys and finding them into master

  SELECT * FROM @child ct WHERE ct.patientid IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT st.keys 
  FROM @SplittedTable AS st 
  WHERE st.splitted  NOT IN (SELECT patientid FROM @parent m ));


  --Use CROSS APPLY to get this done for all rows.
      SELECT DISTINCT ct.*
      FROM @child ct 
      CROSS APPLY dbo.fnSplitString(ct.patientid,',',ct.patientid) ss
     WHERE ss.splitdata NOT IN (SELECT patientid FROM @parent)
```

Comment: Can you post your 15 hours query ?

Comment: And your tables sizes? 15 hours sounds like a lot for split function.

Comment: Comma separated values is indeed a problem... Will people never learn?

Comment: @sagi: table size: 1.2GB

Comment: And your current query?

Comment: try using this splitter http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: @Squirrel: I tried even that but no luck. for table size 20 GB without any index . Hard Luck.... :) "http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/".

Comment: can't you create the index ?

Comment: @Squirrel: No right to do any changes in Customer DB. :)

Comment: @Squirrel: But there is a Hashkey in a table, can i used that?

Comment: then ask DBA to create the necessary index

Comment: And please post your 15 hours query.

Comment: @Squirrel: edited. and added code at last which took more than 15 hours to execute. Please help.